# Remote URL uploading with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, paperclip

I am trying to allow users to upload images via a remote URL.

My normal select file image upload works perfectly fine.

I am getting rollback transactions on submit for a URL uploaded image.

LOG:

```
Started POST "/images" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-16 23:33:52 -0600
Processing by ImagesController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"rYIESJ0zLKaXx1ci+9utsZUxEEBs8rS5eanKvYoz4zoESAgqI8 AaPlyy00SlmStBJMYt4RRiAsv+v4ksuWGdeA==", "image"=>{"image_url"=>"http://bangalorefoodfete.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/food-61.jpg"}, "commit"=>"Submit Photo"}
  (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered images/new.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.erb (7.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 5398ms (Views: 48.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

EDIT:

Error message received.

Image remote url is invalid or inaccessible

This notice is pulled from here:

**image.rb:**

```
validates_presence_of :image_remote_url, :if => :image_url_provided?, :message => 'is invalid or inaccessible'
```

**Image.rb:**

```
require 'open-uri'

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :image, 
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",

:url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename", 
:styles => { :medium => "600x600>", :thumb => "100x100#" }

before_validation :download_remote_image, :if => :image_url_provided?

validates_attachment :image,
content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg",       "image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }


validates_presence_of :image_remote_url, :if => :image_url_provided?, :message => 'is invalid or inaccessible'

private

 def image_url_provided?
 !self.image_url.blank?
end

def download_remote_image
 io = open(URI.parse(image_url))
 self.original_filename = io.base_uri.path.split('/').last
 self.image = io
 self.image_remote_url = image_url
 rescue # catch url errors with validations instead of exceptions    (Errno::ENOENT, OpenURI::HTTPError, etc...)
end
end
```

relevant new.html.erb:

```
<%= form.text_field :image_url %><br>
```

images_controller.rb:

```
lass ImagesController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_image, only: [:show]

 def new
   @image = Image.new
 end  


 def create
  @image = Image.create( user_params )


   if @image.save
     redirect_to @image

   else
     render 'new'

   end
  end

  def show

  end  


  private

  def user_params
   params.require(:image).permit(:image, :title, :description, :image_remote_url, :image_url)
  end  

 def find_image

    @image = Image.find(params[:id])

  end
end
```

relevant schema.rb:

```
create_table "images", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string   "title"
   t.text     "description"
   t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
   t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
   t.string   "image_file_name"
   t.string   "image_content_type"
   t.integer  "image_file_size"
   t.datetime "image_updated_at"
   t.string   "image_url"
   t.string   "image_remote_url"
end
```

I am running Rails 4.2.4 with Paperclip v4.3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

In models/image.rb I changed:

```
def download_remote_image
io = open(URI.parse(image_url))
self.original_filename = io.base_uri.path.split('/').last
self.image = io
self.image_remote_url = image_url
 rescue
end
end
```

to this:

```
 def download_remote_image
io = open(URI.parse(image_url))
self.original_filename = io.base_uri.path.split('/').last
self.image = io
self.image_remote_url = image_url

end
end
```

I removed the rescue, created a migration to add original_filename to my images table and boom, problem solved!

Comment: what is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: Wow Sorry, totally forgot to add the issue. Basically I am getting rollback transactions on the image, it will upload, then rollback, upload then rollback, then navigate me to the show action with a missing.jpg instead of the Image

Comment: remove all code in download_remote_url function and add this just one line 'self.image = open(image_url)' and at the very top write this line require 'rest-open-uri'

Comment: cannot load such file -- rest-open-uri

Comment: you need to install this gem before you can use it https://github.com/rfletcher/rest-open-uri

Comment: Did that and still got same error.

Comment: Did you add it in gem file or did you just install it?

Comment: I added it too my gentile then ran bundle install.

Comment: okay lets try another way, add **require 'open-uri'** at the top and remove **require rest-open-uri** than try to run

Comment: Tried that. No luck, get a validation error as described in the comment below and the edit in the OP.

Comment: Do you have a place where I can look the code?

Comment: The op has all of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

`ROLLBACK` is usually caused by validation errors. Put this at the top of your `new.html.erb` to show your validation errors:

```
<% if @image.errors.any? %>
  <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
     <p> <%= message %> </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

According to your code, you can get validation error `Image remote url is invalid or inaccessible` only if there's some network error while downloading the image.

You can remove your `rescue` line for debugging purposes and see what kind of error do you get there.

> I get this error: undefined method `original_filename=' for #

This line causes your error:

```
self.original_filename = io.base_uri.path.split('/').last
```

If you don't need to store `original_filename`, just remove the line. Otherwise add this column to your `images` table:

```
$ rails g migration AddOriginalFilenameToImages original_filename
$ rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Okay, did that. What I got in the <li> was Image remote url is invalid or inaccessible. Something is causing it to fail the validation but it will not show me what that is.

Comment: I have checked my validates_attachment and all seems fine there. Not sure what else could be causing it to throw that msg. Can you see anything in the code?

Comment: Could you please update your question with exact text of errors your get?

Comment: @Colinm Are there any new errors, when you remove `rescue` line?

Comment: Yes, I get this error: undefined method `original_filename=' for #<Image:0x007ffa49a656d0>

Comment: @Colinm Huh! Don't you have `original_filename` column your table?

Comment: I do not, I have a image_file_name. Should I add original_filename?

Comment: @Colinm Updated my answer.

Comment: Added original_filename to my images table and removed rescue. Problem Solved.